# Network programming with C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, packet-capture

I have a project to do which is packet monitoring.
I want to capture each packet receive by specified network interface.

I want to know what I should start with to do my project ....
should I learn socket programming first or what?
should I learn how to use winpcap under C# or just do my own function.

please advice me from where I should start!!!

I know there are many code in C# out there in the internet for this but I want to learn it by myself but I do not know from where to star!

Comment: Any packet capturing framework will make you specify the interface that's being sniffed to that's taken care of. Then download wireshark and get a feel for what types of traffic are send across the net and how to filter them to narrow your results. Socket programming is generally for writing point-to-point application-level communications applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sould definitely learn the basics of socket programming first so you understand a little bit about what's going on. Next, I would look into programming using [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/), which is a packet capturing library. It's not built directly for .NET but there are, I believe, .NET wrappers or if nothing else you could call the functions by using COM Interop.

Answer (score 4):

I agree using WinPcap is probably a good idea.  Specifically, look at [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/).  it is actively maintained.  In fact, there was a release today.

Comment: +1 for SharpPcap. I've used it, developed it, and like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplx.com).

It is a very active .NET wrapper for WinPcap wrapper with a vast packet interpretation library. It has great quality and performance.